# HAProxy needs restart if origin of a listener changes

Tags: networking, proxy, haproxy

Bear with me because, I understand the problem but none of the terminology needed to Google this properly.

Say I have an EC2 in a public subnet. I install HAProxy in it to tunnel to a resource in a private VPC. The configuration file looks like this:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        maxconn 4000
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 777

listen myserver
bind 0.0.0.0:443
        timeout connect 96h
        timeout client 96h
        timeout server 96h
        mode tcp
        server singleserver private.hostedzone.cname:443
```

This works fine. Now, `singleserver private.hostedzone.cname` is another underlying CNAME that points to let's say another EC2 in a private subnet.

Here's the problem: If the EC2 that `singleserver private.hostedzone.cname` changes, HAProxy needs to be restarted for connections to resume properly. If I understand this correctly, this is because HAProxy caches the actual origin of `singleserver private.hostedzone.cname` on boot instead of in runtime. Can I change something in the configuration above to do it in runtime or something similar?

Also, if the config raises concerns, keep in mind that there's security groups, IAM and other things on top and that the host is not SSHable. :)

Comment: "lso, if the config raises concerns" as you describe it, we can model this generally and ignore the AWS components.  "underlying CNAME that points to let's say another EC2" CNAME has a TTL.  You need a better system for registering hosts with HAProxy - it can handle multiple hosts well but not if they're all just behind one cname record.    "96h" really?  You want to wait 4 days before you timeout your connections?   That's ridiculous in my mind.

Comment: @erik258 i ommited a lot of details to simplify the question. `private.hostedzone.cname` is a CNAME actually for an AWS OpenSearch cluster with a custom endpoint, so I actually can't set it up with the IP and if nodes change on a rolling update, this problem happens. And the 96H I know don't make sense for regular use cases, but we can have long running in Glue or EMR for extreme length backfill, that can run for almost 2 days on the cluster, so the 4 days is just in case. This are data engineering resources, not actual webservers.